# Is checking if not nil before sending a release message good practice?

Tags: objective-c

when releasing an instance that could exist or not, I usually write this:

if (object != nil) [object release];

but since sending a message to nil is not a problem, is that conditional necessary?

I suppose the question comes down to this: which uses more overhead, comparing an object to nil, or sending nil a message?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [this page](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/universal_binary/universal_binary_tips/chapter_5_section_22.html) which explains that passing messages to nil (to generalize your example) is perfectly fine.

As to what has more overhead, any performance impact will be negligible to the overall performance of the system (don't get into the habit of premature optimization).

Comment: Sending the message will do the nil check either way, so doing the nil check separately is not an optimization. It's an anti-optimization.

Answer (score 5):

When I was coding more C++ than Obj-C, I would always write code to check for `nil` -- because it was a note to myself that this pointer is allowed to be `nil`. Now, I let `objc_msgSend` deal with it, since I've grown more comfortable reading the code with the assumption that any pointer could validly be `nil`.

On a "safe coding" level, I think that it's more important to always set your pointers to `nil` after each release (possibly exluding a `release` in the `dealloc` method). This way, you ensure that your pointer is never invalid (it is either valid, or `nil`).

Answer (score 2):

That check is not necessary. Unless you're doing a LOT of iterations of this code (10,000s, maybe more), the time differential is insignificant.

Comment: And even then, you should use a profiler before doing any optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Obj-C checks for `nil`, so there's no need to do it twice.

```
[object release]; object = nil;
```

If you want add some extra code there, it's much better to set the pointer *to* `nil` afterwards, so it would be immune to double-free.